# Split javascript object with key value as written as strings

Tags: javascript

The code pattern reads the `dataset` on the HTML element and receives the following output.

```js
var objectString = '{"name": "Name", "description": "desc", "extra": "extra"}'
  
console.log(typeof objectString)
```

Can you please suggest an efficient way to convert it to key: value pair?

Since `JSON.parse(objectString)` later results in

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

It supposes that the is already an object, but doing `objectString.name` returns in `undefined`

**UPDATE**

My apologies, JSON.parse does work in the browser. But I didn't mention that the code project has jest tester verifying it, so it throws and Syntax Error. That's why I am looking for a similar approach.

Is it possible to split the string words, loop over and return an object with as `key: pair`?

Comment: JSON.parse works good...

Comment: Please include a [mcve] showing that JSON.parse does not work

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8nqqodek/) Works good. Check what input you're feeding into the parser.

Comment: indeed parse does work in the browser, but I didn't mention that the code has jest tester verifying it, so it throws and Syntax Error

Comment: Voting to close as you haven't given enough information for us to solve your issue. `JSON.parse(objectString)` will obviously work, but you have not given us any other code to work with. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @volna did you check my answer?

Comment: It looks like somewhere in your code you're parsing a result of `Object.toString()` method. Where, how and why can't be solved with the provided code. I'd suggest you to take a closer look at your code, and especially the line the error occurs. If you still can't solve the issue, then ask a new question with more complete code.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean with "another approach". Is it required that you have the end-result in an JSON object? Is it required to parse at all? Can you write the JSON string directly in javascript instead of parsingfrom javascript object string to JSON object?

Comment: where are you getting `objectString`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *That's why I am looking for a similar approach*

Here's a code that will convert your string to an object. It's just some string manipulation to get the format right. Then a `forEach` loop to append the key/value pairs into the object.

```js
// removes white spaces and first and last characters around string
let shape = s => s.trim().substring(1, s.trim().length - 1);

// convert the string into an object
let convertToObj = function(str) {

  let obj = {};
  
  shape(str).split(',').forEach(e => {
    [key, value] = e.split(':');
    obj[shape(key)] = shape(value)
  });
  
  return obj

}

// preview
obj = convertToObj('{"name": "Name", "description": "desc", "extra": "extra"}')
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: A very elegant es6 solution, thank you, Ivan. I did take my time going through each step which made me learn a lot :)

Comment: @volna. Thank you volna, I'm happy to have helped. I too learn a lot about es6 by reading others' responses. It's so satisfying to write less code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below to get `key : value` as string :

```js
var objectString = '{"name": "Name", "description": "desc", "extra": "extra"}';

var jsonOb = JSON.parse(objectString);

for (var key in jsonOb) {
    if (jsonOb.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " : " + jsonOb[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter, may I know the reason to downvote? Please mention it

Comment: OP says they are getting a syntax error, this doesn't solve any syntax errors. Not my down vote though.

Comment: @Teemu thanks for your reply but this is actual question **Can you please suggest an efficient way to convert it to key: value pair?**

Comment: And my solution is giving the result.

Comment: @VicJordan, true your code solves the issue. But OP's question was unclear.

Comment: my apologies for confusion, did update the question

Comment: @Ivan thanks for understanding but it was not that much unclear. Sometimes people are not able to express what they want.

Comment: My downvote was because you've literally pasted what's been in the comment (saying it works but with a code sample OP posted that he said it doesn't work) and for me that's just a cheap way to get up-votes. Anyway; seems like OP just changed the context of the question, so I'm removing my downvote. However you're still not given anything new to the table that OP doesn't seem to know as he stated that `JSON.parse` is giving him an error, perhaps not enough context to base an answer on?

Comment: let it rain on me boys :))